# What does it represent when a probability is multiplied a number of times by itself?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$P(X=i)=\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}, i=0,1,\ldots, \min(n,m).$$

The above probability represents suppose that a sample of size $n$ is to be chosen randomly (without replacement) from an urn containing $N$ balls, of which $m$ are white and $N-m$ are black. If we let $X$ denote the number of white balls selected, then **the probability of getting exactly $i$ white balls** is $P(X=i)=\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}, i=0,1,\ldots, \min(n,m).$

My question is:

> What does the following probability represent $$\big(\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}\big)^2$$?

Comment: Well, "doing it twice"?  That is, you require that you draw your sample with exactly $i$ White and then you throw all the balls back in the urn and you do it again.

Comment: Yes as lulu is saying doing the same from same initial conditions so you need to back the balls up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the probability of getting exactly $i$ white balls in each of two (independent) draws of $m$ balls, meaning that you replace the balls you drew in between the two draws.

Comment: it's the same. Suppose you have two identical urns and two people doing the same experiment. Then the probability of both getting exactly i white balls is as ABC asked

Comment: Is it okay if I think it as: I have two urns, urn A and urn B. Each urn contains $N$ balls, of which $m$ are white and $N-m$ are black. From each urn I draw sample of $n$ balls. Then $\big(\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}\big)^2=$ (probability of getting exactly $i$ white balls from urn A **and** probability of getting exactly $i$ white balls from urn B )?

Comment: @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez Thank you. I hadn't seen your comment before posting my previous comment.

Comment: As $P(X=i)$, how can I denote $\big(\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}\big)^2$?

Comment: two experiments, so $X_1,X_2$, then the probability searched is $P(X_1=i,X_2=i)$

Comment: @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez For a small trial, I found that $$\big(\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}\big)^2\ne \frac{\binom{2m}{2i}\binom{2N-2m}{2n-2i}}{\binom{2N}{2n}}.$$ Why  **"combining all the balls from the two experiment  and calculating the probability of getting exactly $2i$ white balls"** is not same as of **"having two identical urns and two people doing the same experiment, then calculating  the probability of both getting exactly $i$ white balls"**?

Comment: 'cause when you combine balls lose the independence. That's why you need two urns.

Comment: @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez Thanks a lot. A last question: if $\big(\frac{\binom{m}i\binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}\big)^{10}$, can I denote it as $P(\cap_{j=1}^{10}X_j=i)$?

Comment: yes, just specify that $\lbrace X_j\rbrace_{j=1}^{10}$ are independient experiments equal to $X$